# Does downloading the same torrent from more than one tracker increase the sources / seeds?

Tags: bittorrent

Does downloading the same torrent from more than one server increase the sources / seeds?

**edit**:
What I meant with servers is those like *mininova*, *isohunt* and the like.

Now I know those aren't the *trackers*, what I want to know is if when more than one of those indexing sites are linked for the same torrent, if they likely contain different lists of trackers, so getting the torrent from both sites will increase the trackers, hence the seeds, or if it's just in case one of the sites goes down.

I guess I can test this getting one torrent from one site with a torrent client and the same torrent, from another site with another client and comparing the list of trackers and the amount of seeders and leechers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you contact multiple trackers for the same torrent, you get peer information from each of them. Since trackers only send you e.g. 80 peers each, you can get a lot more peers if you contact multiple trackers.

If you can handle many connections, it will likely increase your download speed.

Answer (score 3):

Bit-torrent doesn't have servers, just trackers.

Having multiple trackers for a torrent generally improves its performance. Having alternate trackers means you can connect to more peers and seeders, thus allowing more stable connections. This provides redundancy in the case that one tracker fails, the other trackers can continue to maintain the swarm for the torrent.

Trackers are placed in groups, or tiers, with a tracker randomly chosen from the top tier and tried, moving to the next tier if all the trackers in the top tier fail. If one has too many trackers, it might take longer before a suitable tracker is found and for the download to start.

Comment: I never knew exactly if the tracker was the website where you get the torrent from or a separate server. Anyway, what I meant is, does getting the same torrent from (say) mininova AND isohunt make a difference, or is it the same? I don't know, maybe you get the same torrent from both sites but the torrent has the same tracker info inside and getting both doesn't make any difference. eztv.it for example, lists more than one link for the same torrent, I always click two or three but wonder if it's of any help.

Comment: its a seperate server - most torrent sites are not much more than web sites with a bunch of torrent files. EZTV tends to have different torrents of the same show

Comment: The torrent contains its trackers, so getting the same torrent does not help, unless the tracker site added itself into the list.

Comment: isoHunt is an aggregator that adds a bunch of different trackers into one nice .torrent file for you to use.  You are unlikely to find any additional trackers that recognize the torrent.

Answer (score 2):

Servers? No, trackers, potentially - though its a matter of having different trackers, and DHT might cover some of those.

Comment: It also depends on is that one torrent on each tracker the exact same torrent?

Comment: yes. that too...

Comment: @MrStatic  That's why we have torrent hashes. Instead of searching for torrent by name, search it by hash. Most bittorrent programs will detect if you're adding multiple torrents with same hash an then just import trackers form the new torrent file.